# How to prevent overflow of content in the y axis when user resize?

Tags: css

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-cartwright-gqcuzt

```
// css
h1 {
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
//html
<body>
  <h1 class="red">
    contents...
  </h1>
  <h1 class="blue">
    contents...
  </h1>
</body>
```

As shown in the sandbox, the min-height seems to have no effect when the height of the box is smaller than the content size and causes an overflow.

How to produce the desired effect of forcing the box not to shrink smaller than the content when user resizes?

Comment: _"As shown in the sandbox"_ - a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, do not just send us to external platforms.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to display the container as a `flex` and set the flex direction to  `column`.